# MomentJS can't convert a date with format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.fff Z

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to convert the next date using MomentJS:

```js
const moment = require('moment');

var datetime = "2017-11-19 02:45:22.011 +00:00";
var newDate = moment(datetime);
```

But it fails and the next message appears:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or 
>        ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not 
>        reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats 
>        are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. 
>        Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more 
>        info.

Snippet showing the issue:

```js
var datetime = "2017-11-19 02:45:22.011 +00:00";
var newDate = moment(datetime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I also tried using:

```
moment.utc(datetime);
```

but failed.

Comment: So... what's your *question*? Someone's put a lot of effort into writing a comprehensive error message from `moment`, so what don't you understand?

Comment: How to do it @jonrshape

Comment: Well, where does that date come from? Why is it not in a standard format? Can you alter the upstream system? If not, *"how can I parse an arbitrary datetime string"* seems a bit broad, perhaps you could do some research.

Comment: Upvoted and posted an answer because it was tricky to understand why `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.fff Z` is not recognized as ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reformatting the date string from:

```
2017-11-19 02:45:22.011 +00:00
```

To:

```
2017-11-19T02:45:22.011Z
```

Solved it

Answer (score 2):

As [`moment(String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) docs says:

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats, we then check if the string matches the [RFC 2822 Date time format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) before dropping to the fall back of `new Date(string)` if a known format is not found.

`2017-11-19 02:45:22.011 +00:00` is not in ISO 8601 compliant format because there is a **space** between fractional seconds and UTC offset (`2017-11-19 02:45:22.011+00:00` is an ISO 8601 version of your input). So you can use [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), here a live sample:

```js
var datetime = "2017-11-19 02:45:22.011 +00:00";
var newDate = moment(datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.fff Z');
console.log(newDate.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```